# TChart doesn't render on form creation if TeeOpenGL.Active is true

Tags: delphi-xe2, teechart

if I set TeeOpenGL.Active to true in FormCreate, then TChart appears as white blank square. What can be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this is a bug. I have added it (TV52016245) to the defect list to be fixed for next releases.